# MYSQL 5.7 How to query if JSON field contains at least one object with attribute greater than value?

Tags: mysql, sql, json, mysql-5.7

I have a JSON field **courses** in my table with this value:

```json
[
   {
      "name":"Corso1",
      "description":"Descrizione",
      "own_place_teaching":true,
      "own_place_teaching_rate":"50",
      "own_place_teaching_duration":"60",
      "home_teaching":true,
      "home_teaching_rate":"70",
      "home_teaching_duration":"60",
      "online_teaching":false,
      "online_teaching_rate":"",
      "online_teaching_duration":""
   }
]
```

How do I select all records with courses having:

own_place_teaching_rate greater than 30,

or a home_teaching_rate greater than 30,

or a online_teaching_rate greater than 30?

Thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

Your query is very easy.

```
SELECT * 
  FROM your_table 
 WHERE JSON_EXTRACT(courses '$.own_place_teaching_rate') > 30
    OR JSON_EXTRACT(courses '$.home_teaching_rate') > 30 
    OR JSON_EXTRACT(courses '$.online_teaching_rate') >30;
```

if you use this query, you will get the result you want.

Comment: I get no rows from this query.
If I try the query:

SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(courses, '$.own_place_teaching_rate')  FROM my_table

All rows are null