How to query with operators in JSON array column?
"Detail" column
[
 {
   "bedrooms_count" : 2,
   "bathrooms_count" : 5
 }
]

I want to query the records where bedrooms count >= 1 and <=5*.
This is the query currently working with, and the result is empty although data is present:
->where('detail->bedrooms_count', '>=', 1)->where('detail->bedrooms_count', '<=', 5);

Although it will work on only JSON object type, the column is an array type.

Your query targets an array of JSON objects instead of a singular JSON object, which alters the path required to access bedrooms_count.

This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64383812/mysql-5-7-how-to-query-if-json-field-contains-at-least-one-object-with-attribute

Correct JSON path for shown JSON value is not detail->bedrooms_count but detail->'$[0].bedrooms_count'. And you'd use WhereBetween.

@try.aaam There are no results using that solution as the owner comment stated that

@Akina $q->whereBetween("detail->'$[0].bedrooms_count'", [$value['from'], $value['to']]) I got 0 result using this.

I got 0 result using this You either provide something incorrectly or do something wrongly. See https://dbfiddle.uk/pnPfx_-x

I guess, you can use MYSQL JSON_CONTAINS() function to look inside the array of json object. I found this post to be relatable and came up with below query:
SELECT *
FROM your_table_name
WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(detail, '{"bedrooms_count": 2}', '$') = 1
   OR JSON_CONTAINS(detail, '{"bedrooms_count": 3}', '$') = 1
   OR JSON_CONTAINS(detail, '{"bedrooms_count": 4}', '$') = 1
   OR JSON_CONTAINS(detail, '{"bedrooms_count": 5}', '$') = 1;


In my case the count is dynamic value from request and can have over 100 for other fields.
